# How do the Hati and Sköll equipment bonuses stack with other bonuses?

Tags: runescape

The Hati gloves give double combat experience and the Sköll boots give double Agility and Woodcutting experience. If I wear those and have some other equipment that also gives bonus experience in the same skills, what kind of total bonus do I get?

For example, if I am wearing the Hati gloves and a full sacred clay set for some combat style (which also gives double experience) do I end up getting double experience (if they do not combine at all), triple experience (if the bonuses add), or quadruple experience (if the bonuses multiply)?

Do the bonuses stack the same way with different equipment combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial experimentation shows that the bonuses stack multiplicatively: When cutting ivy, which has a base experience of 332.5 experience per cut, just wearing hat and legs for lumberjack outfit gives 3.3 bonus experience per successful cut (about 101% experience). Wearing just the Sköll boots gives 332.5 bonus experience (200% experience as expected). Wearing all of those gives 339.1 experience (202% experience). The bonus from the boots combines with the bonus from the Seer's headband 2+ the same way (giving 220% experience total).

However, wearing the boots and using a sacred clay tool at the same time gives the same bonus as using either individually for a total of 200% experience. This also happens with the combination of the Hati gloves with sacred clay armor and weapon.

In addition, the boot/glove bonus experience does not stack with the bonus from the bonus experience weekend.